# What sets Apple iPad cases apart from other iPad case companies?

Tags: ipad

Is it necessary to buy an iPad case from Apple, or are other companies just as suitable? FOr example, I recently discovered a company called Domeo Products. I found their website, domeoproducts.com, and it looks like they have some great cases. However, I am unfamiliar with them and do not know how they compare to companies like Apple.

Comment: I should perhaps have closed this as not constructive. Feel free to ask about improving this on [meta] if the guidelines for asking an objective, non-hardware shopping question.

Answer (score 2):

All depends on your needs. I personally don't like the cases from Apple. I think there are better 3rd party cases. OtterBox is a good option. I have one for my iPad and I really like it. It's rugged and versitile. When shopping for something like this, I like to research. I go to places like Amazon and read the reviews. Just remember, You have to take some of the reviews with a grain of salt. However, it's a good place to get options.